# Why does K-nearest neighbor algorithm suffer from curse of dimensionality?

Tags: knn

As per the algorithm we are considering only the k-nearest neighbors. Then How does it depends on other features ?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem programming-related. You shall have better chance to get an answer on SO's companion website, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346775/confusion-related-to-curse-of-dimensionality-in-k-nearest-neighbor

Answer (score 2):

The curse of dimensionality in the k-NN context basically means that Euclidean distance is unhelpful in high dimensions because all vectors are almost equidistant to the search query vector (imagine multiple points lying more or less on a circle with the query point at the center; the distance from the query to all data points in the search space is almost the same).

Quoted from Wikipedia!